# Is it possible to pass variables to jquery's css function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'd like to set css of a div element dynamically using jQuery css() function instead of using string literals/ string constants for the css() function. Is it possible?

Instead of using the following codes with string literals:

```
$('#myDiv').css('color', '#00ff00');
```

I would like to use variables to set css for #myDiv element like

Version 1:

```
var propertyName = get_propery_name(myVariable1); // function get_propery_name() returns a string like 'background-color'
var value = get_value(myVariable2) ; //  function get_value() returns a string like '#00ff00'
$('#myDiv').css(propertyName, value);
```

Version 2: (just hard coded to see if they work without calling custom functions like version 1 above):

```
var propertyName = 'background-color';
var value = '#00ff00';
$('#divLeftReportView').css(propertyName, value);
```

Both variable versions of codes do not work.  Please help.  Thanks.

Comment: There is nothing special in it. Both variants should work well: http://jsfiddle.net/UQWyH/

Comment: Did this answer your question? Please accept an answer if one of them helped you

Answer (score 2):

Both of your examples will work just fine. I would suggest just a bit cleaner approach (personal syntax preference):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#myDiv').css(get_propery_name(myVariable1), get_value(myVariable2));
}
```

Here's [a working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesHill/AqB6S/).

If you want to take it a step further, you can return a CSS map instead of strings:

```
$('#divLeftReportView').css(GetCssMap("foo"));

function GetCssMap(mapIdentifier) {
    return { "background-color" : "#00ff00" }
}
```

Here's [a working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesHill/kdYnf/).

Answer (score 1):

The code you posted here should work. I have done both versions of what you are trying to do several times. If it is not working, there is a good chance that something is wrong somewhere else in your javascript OR that you do not have the correct selector/id for the element(s) which you want to change.

Try adding `alert("test");` immediately after `$('#divLeftReportView').css(propertyName, value);`. If you get the popup saying "test" then the problem is with your selector. If not, then the problem is a bug in your javascript.

Also try adding `$('#divLeftReportView').css("background-color", "#00ff00");` in the same place. That will confirm whether or not the selector is working.

Comment: Thanks. I found the problem is I use upper case for property name like BACKGOUND-COLOR for jQuery css() method, so my codes did not work with things like $('#divLeftReportView').css("BACKGOUND-COLOR", "#00ff00");  It turns out the property name must be lower case.  So, the codes should be $('#divLeftReportView').css("background-color", "#00ff00");

Answer (score 1):

Seems to work fine at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/6wHtW/

Make sure you run your code after the DOM ready event..

```
$(function(){
    var propertyName = 'background-color';
    var value = '#00ff00';
    $('#divLeftReportView').css(propertyName, value);
});
```

otherwise your elements might not be present in the DOM..

Comment: What if the value for the 'value' variable is got from an input textbox (user enters) like: var value = $('#myTextBox').val();  ?  What I mean is how the value of 'value' variable is converted to a string literal or string constant?

Comment: since it is a string it will work as is... whether you pass a string literal or a variable holding a string it is the same thing..

Answer (score 1):

You can also pass multiple CSS parameters within one variable as an array:

```
$(function(){
    var divStyle = {'background-color': '#00ff00', 'color': '#000000'}
    $('#divID').css(divStyle);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

yes, using jQuery attr method you can change css dynamically

```
var height=$(".sampleClass1").innerHeight();
$('.sammpleClass2').attr('style', 'min-height:'+height+' !important');
```